# Flask-Admin - adding a custom view

Tags: python-2.7, flask, flask-admin

I am developing a web-app using Flask-Admin.

All is smooth and fine when using ModelViews, but when it comes to subclassing a BaseView I simply can't get it working.

I am trying to add my own view so I can display different data from the database.

Also I can't call the database when using the BaseView.

Here is my code:

**app/__init__.py**

```
#!/flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
```

**app/models.py**

```
 #!/flask/bin/python
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, BOOLEAN
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
import random
import string

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    name = Column(String(32))
    token = Column(String(16), primary_key=True)
    originator = Column(String(12))
    active = Column(BOOLEAN, default=True)
    logging = Column(BOOLEAN)


    def __init__(self, name='', token='no_token', account='test', originator='Test', active=True, logging=0):
        self.name = name
        self.token = token
        self.originator = originator
        self.active = active
        self.logging = logging


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**app/views.py**

```
#imports ommited

from app.models import User
#this works totally fine
class UserView(ModelView):
    form_columns = ('name', 'originator','account_type')
    column_display_pk=True
    column_searchable_list = ('name')
    form_excluded_columns = ('logging')

    def __init__(self, session, **kwargs):
        super(UserView, self).__init__(models.User, session, **kwargs)

class CRUDSettings(BaseView):
    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
    #HERE I don't have access to my User DB object.
    I tried with db.session.query(User).all() - db is undefined
    I tried many other ways but I can't get all users so I can populate the select dropdown box.
    users = User  <----------------------------- ?
    return self.render('crud.html', accounts = users)
```

**templates/crud.html**

```
{% extends 'admin/master.html' %}
    {% block body %}
     <div class="row">
               <form action="/" id="form_acc" name="form_acc" method="POST">
                 <label id="lbl_acc">Account:</label>
                <select name="d_account" id="d_account">
                 {% for acc in accounts %}
                 <option value="{{acc}}" {{'selected' if selected_account==acc else ''}}>{{acc}}</option>
                 {% endfor %}
                 </select>


            <button class="button " id="brand_submit"  type="submit">Go</button>

        </form>
      </div>

 {% endblock %}
```

**run.py**

```
#!/flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.admin import Admin
from app import views

app = Flask(__name__)

SERVER = ''
PORT = ''
DATABASE = ''
USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''
SSL = ''

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s?%s' % (
    USERNAME, PASSWORD, SERVER, PORT, DATABASE, SSL)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    admin = Admin(app)
    admin.add_view(views.UserView(db.session))
    admin.add_view(views.CRUDSettings(name='CRUD Settings', endpoint='crud'))
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'
    app.run('127.0.0.1', 5001, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the app `db` variable when you call `CRUDSettings` constructor. Refactor your view model to something like the following:

```
class CRUDSettings(BaseView):

    def __init__(self, session, name=None, category=None, endpoint=None, url=None, static_folder=None,
                 menu_class_name=None, menu_icon_type=None, menu_icon_value=None):

        self.session = session

        super(CRUDSettings, self).__init__(name, category, endpoint, url, static_folder,
                                           menu_class_name=menu_class_name, menu_icon_type=menu_icon_type,
                                           menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)


    @expose('/')
    def index(self):
        # users = self.session.query(User).all()
```

Now set-up your view as follows:

```
admin.add_view(views.CRUDSettings(session=db.session, name='CRUD Settings', endpoint='crud'))
```